# How do I include another file in an assembly file?

Tags: assembly, x86, include, x86-64

I work with x86-64 Architecture and would like to include a separate file into an assembly (.S) file. The separate file contains a table

`tab: .quad 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81, 100, ...`

and the main code has these declarations:

`.intel_syntax noprefix
.global sqrt
.data
.text
sqrt:`

How do I make the code see the table as it would be in the .data section?

Comment: You can either use `.include` to include the file in the assembler, `#include` to include it in the preprocessor or you mark `tab` as global and let the linker deal with this.

Answer (score 0):

Do `.include "filename.s"`, where `filename.s` is the file that you want to include.